# Where the URI constants should be defined? How to reduce the *.java interdependency?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

**Summary:** Should the URIs be defined as the content provider class constants, or distributed to the table-wrapper class definitions? Is there any better way to implement all the things? Is there the single prefered way of the implementation? How to break the interdependency?

*The database-table wrapper class:* To avoid direct construction of SQL commands (to create an abstraction layer), the classes like below--with various constants and some static methods--are created to wrap the tables.

*The database helper class:* The database helper class is the abstraction for the database. It uses the the above-like table wrappers to wrap working with more tables together.

*The content provider class:* An Android `XxxxContentProvider` is sent various URIs to query/insert/update/delete the required data. The `ContentProvider` subclass should implement methods named like that and several other methods. Each of the data manipulation methods parses the URI (usually using the `UriMatcher` instance), and decides what exactly should be done.

**Update:** I have found the `ContactsContract.java` in the Android core part. Is that the way to reduce interdependency? Is it the solution of the kind: *"When things between two sides become too complex, put an agent to the middle"* ?

Comment: Maybe you should see how android has implemented it by seeing its source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Summary: Should the URIs be defined as the content provider class
>   constants, or distributed to the table-wrapper class definitions? Is
>   there any better way to implement all the things? Is there the single
>   prefered way of the implementation? How to break the interdependency?

I think there's a preferred way of doing things and that is, like you've already seen, a `Contract` class. This is underline in the guide for the `ContentProviders` on the android site.

The discussion would revolve around your `ContentProvier` being exported or not. If your provider will be used by other apps then definitely go with a `Contract` class wrapping your constants. This would make it easier to maintain in the long run and it will also be easier to expose those constants.

If the provider will be private then you do have other options too, but I would still use a `Contract` class. I wouldn't put the constants in the *The database helper class* because they really don't belong there. Between the *The database-table wrapper class* and the *The content provider class* I would choose the `ContentProvider` class because at a later point you may decide to drop the *database-table wrapper class*(which wouldn't happen in the case of the `ContentProvider` subclass). But, as I already said, I would still use the `Contract` class, even if right now the provider is not exported you might decide in the future that you do want to expose it and a `Contract` class will make that switch much easier.

Comment: Should also the `UriMatcher` be the part of the `Contract` class?

Comment: @pepr No. The `UriMatcher` rules are tied to the `ContentProvider` and I wouldn't put it in the `Contract` class.

Comment: Then, should the strings or string fragments used in the `UriMatcher` be the constants from the `Contract` class? Or in other words... Is there any really serious reason not to duplicate the strings in the PATHs, URIs, and UriMatcher's patterns? Should one try to keep the DRY principle in the case to avoid possible typo errors, or does the reality show that it is not a problem at all?

Comment: @pepr Ignore my last deleted comment. *Is there any really serious reason not to duplicate the strings in the PATHs, URIs, and UriMatcher's patterns?* - No, except the DRY principle you mention. **I** would duplicate them to keep the `Contract` class as light and clear as possible. *in the case to avoid possible typo errors* - this depends on the developer :)